# Cannot make centred text next to image in div responsive in small devices

Tags: html, css

I have an image in a div next to some text in a div, and I have centred the text to some satisfaction in the desktop, but the text is not responsive. When I shrink the browser to mobile size the text is superimposed on the responsive images. You can see here: https://www.artisanbelle.com/ Scroll down to the block where the testimonials are and you'll see what I mean.

There are multiple divs of class 'pic-testimonial'. Before I added translate/transform to center the text, my text blocks were responsive in mobile but they were not centered. I need an approach that allows me to center the text within that div but which maintains the responsiveness of the overall structure. What I have doesn't do that and I am not sure what to do. The 'center' tag did not work. To clarify, without the transform, the text was sitting at the top of the large div (the size of the div is fine btw). The transform created the effect that I wanted but only at desktop level. It is wonky at mobile, as described. Does anyone have an alternative way to center text within a div block that is responsive?

Also I would prefer a solution that is not deprecated in HTML5 if possible. Thanks.

I have tried the following code: (snippet only provided)

```
<div class="testimonial-container">

<div class="pic-testimonial">
  <div class="testimonial-imga"><figure class="photo1"><img class="testimonial-photo" src="http://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/amandac.jpg" alt="Amanda C"></figure> </div>
    <div class="testimonial-texta"><div class="test-text">      
     <p>"These white topaz earrings are gorgeous. The stones catch the light and are so pretty. They can be dressed up or down and the craftsmanship is top quality. A great pair of earrings that go with everything." <br>- Amanda Coldwell</p> </div> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test-text {
    position: relative;
}

.test-text p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-16%, 80%);
  text-align: center;
}
.testimonial-imga, .testimonial-imgb {
    float: left;
}


.testimonial-texta, .testimonial-textb {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
`   background-color: #DDE1E4;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.testimonial-container {
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Expected/desired output: text centred responsively across all devices
Actual output: Text only centred across desktop device at normal browser size. Text superimposed on images when browser is mobile size
Images are fine and already responsive.

Comment: You want to look at CSS @media. Check it out more https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Yes, thanks, I fixed the problem. I added it in an answer in case it might help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I fixed the problem. I moved the text transform to the desktop section (media queries) and made the width 100% for the .testimonial-texta, .testimonial-textb width attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use center tags

```css
.test-text {
  position: relative;
}

.test-text p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-16%, 80%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="testimonial-container">
    <div class="pic-testimonial">
      <div class="testimonial-imga">
        <figure class="photo1"><img class="testimonial-photo" src="http://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/amandac.jpg" alt="Amanda C"></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-texta">
        <div class="test-text">
          <p>"These white topaz earrings are gorgeous. The stones catch the light and are so pretty. They can be dressed up or down and the craftsmanship is top quality. A great pair of earrings that go with everything." <br>- Amanda Coldwell</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

[read more at](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)

Comment: That did nothing. I want to center the *text* responsively. The images are already centered rsponsively. The code block you wrapped with center tags is already centred responsively. The individual div blocks themselves already center responsively. Before I added the code in test-text using transform and translate, my text was responsive - but it wasn't centered. So, I need a solution that both is both responsive and that centers the text.